# Como pausar e iniciar áudio ao alternar guia no browser?

Tags: javascript, html5

No Doodle do Google do [117º aniversário de Oskar Fischinger](https://www.google.com/doodles/oskar-fischingers-117th-birthday) percebi que é quando altera a aba, a musica para de executar, e quando volta para pagina novamente, ela continua a tocar. Criei um exemplo usando `<audio>`. Veja:

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://www.zedge.net/d2w/4/1631039/878827377/view/?mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Como pausar e iniciar áudio ao alternar aba?

Comment: [Nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7487509/6510304) há os métodos focus e blur. Que ao sair da página você está pausando o video ou audio através do blur, e quando volta a focar é chamado o focus lá você continua a executar o seu video ou audio.

Answer (score 0):

[Esse código](http://jsfiddle.net/WwfFE/5/) deve lhe ajudar, é bem simples de se entender e basta substituir um player de vídeo por áudio, mas de qualquer forma:

Ao sair da tab o código é chamado:

```
if (currentTab == '') {
   //Find current tab:
   currentTab = $('#tabs ul li.active').find('a').attr('href');
}

//Stop playing video:
if (currentTab != '')
   $('div#' + currentTab).find('iframe').attr('src', '');
```

e ao voltar para a tab:

```
var index = $(this).attr('id');
$('div#' + currentTab).find('iframe').attr('src', urls[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta usar o [pageVisibility - w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/)

Um exemplo mais ou menos de como seria:

```
    window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {
       if (document.hidden) {
         console.log('PAUSAR O AUDIO');
       }else {
         console.log('PLAY NO AUDIO');
       }
    });
```